# Observe the variables addresses in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I'm using VS 2012RC and I write some simple C# methods for education purposes. I'm currently learning how exactly C#/.NET works with strings and I want to observe the addresses of my string variables just to see how they behave, but when I try to debug with breakpoint I get only the values of the variables and not their addresses in the memory. I'm pretty sure there's a way to get this info in VS 2012 so I'm looking for a little help on the topic.

Thanks

Leron

Comment: What benefit do you think you'll get from seeing the addresses? I can't remember the last time I needed to care about that...

Comment: You'll probably learn more by reading the documentation on strings that you'll INFER by looking at their addresses (even if you could do so).

Comment: When debugging in VS you can right-click and select 'Go to disassmebly'.

Comment: I've READ how strings are managed in .NET, now I want to SEE it. I don't know what benefit I'll get from it, at least I'll know how to find a variable address in the memory using the VS debugger if nothing else.

Comment: Addresses are helpful in verifying that you don't have two instances of the same object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Place a breakpoint somewhere.

Optionally make an object ID for your variable.

Open your memory window.  ctrl+D,Y

type in your variable name, or the object ID in the address bar.

Enjoy.

Comment: And "just say yes" to abstract knowledge ;-)